# DataGridView Numeric Only Cell?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am new to winforms..I am trying to set two column of DataGridView to Numeric Only.. I do not want user to be able to type anything into a cell unless its a natural number in one column and a numeric value in another(which always one decimal). 
I thought this would be simple.. but even after trying a lot of things from stackoverflow and other sites i am still unable to achieve this.

```
If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 8 Then

    If Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) AndAlso Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> "."c Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End If
```

Comment: I will accept any answer in c# too if it works.. There are online converters available. ;)

Comment: Duplicate Question [Make a specific column only accept numeric value in datagridview in Keypress event][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645458/make-a-specific-column-only-accept-numeric-value-in-datagridview-in-keypress-eve

Comment: used **EditingControlShowing** instead of CellValidating see [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this code

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing

        If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 2 Then

            AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress

        ElseIf DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 1 Then

            AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress1


        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox_keyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)

        If Char.IsDigit(CChar(CStr(e.KeyChar))) = False Then e.Handled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox_keyPress1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)

        If Not (Char.IsDigit(CChar(CStr(e.KeyChar))) Or e.KeyChar = ".") Then e.Handled = True

    End Sub
```

TextBox_keyPress Event for only numeric

TextBox_keyPress1 Event for numeric with decimal value

Comment: I am trying to validate `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` I am not using TextBox.

Comment: yes. you are not using texbox. but you can achieve your goal by writing textbox event and add handler in the DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing event.. you no need to add text box in the form design..

Comment: This my friend is by far the best solution I have come across so far.. I am sorry i took so long to respond. Thanks.
However there is only one thing lacking, which is..
In case of decimal numbers only single decimal is to be allowed.

Comment: @Arbaaz format the decimal cell after the editing or check the particular cell have decimal value. I think format (#,0.0) is the best sloution

Comment: well i tried to check if the cell already has decimal but i always get null reference error ... I have asked this in a new question .. 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/19899456/2064292

Answer (score 1):

If data type validation is only concern then you can use CellValidating event like this

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        //e.FormattedValue  will return current cell value and 
        //e.ColumnIndex & e.RowIndex will rerurn current cell position

        // If you want to validate particular cell data must be numeric then check e.FormattedValue is all numeric 
        // if not then just set  e.Cancel = true and show some message 
        //Like this 

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            if (!IsNumeric(e.FormattedValue))  // IsNumeric will be your method where you will check for numebrs 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter valid numeric data");
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = null;
                e.Cancel = true;

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: How do i clear the cell? I do not want user to be able to type if its not numeric

Comment: Modified my post please check @Arbaaz

Comment: added  [dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = null;]

Comment: @Arbaaz at least the other answer (of SATSON) should work, why did you not leave any comment? You should leave some comment on all the answers to notify them to improve their answer, otherwise you won't have any better answer.

Comment: @KingKing you are right .. my apologies .. 
I have left a comment there now.

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta yes its not clearing the cell.. the value remains as it is in the cell.

Comment: can you write it down in **VB.NET** @NeerajKumarGupta

Comment: used **EditingControlShowing** instead of **CellValidating**

Answer (score 0):

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 6 Then
    If Not IsNumeric(e.FormattedValue) Then
        ' IsNumeric will be your method where you will check for numebrs 
        MessageBox.Show("Enter valid numeric data")
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = Nothing

        e.Cancel = True

    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is an extension of Satish's Solution. It will help to control values of DataGridView Cells. Textbox function has used to attach a cell to textbox-event only. No need to add a text box in a DataGridView or anywhere on the form.

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.EditingControlShowing
    If DataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 2 Then 'Numeric column with decimal point
        AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress

    ElseIf DataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 3 Then 'Numeric column without Decimal
        AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress1

    ElseIf DataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 4 Then 'Selected Values only
        AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress2

    ElseIf DataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 5 Then 'Email Column
        AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress3

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_keyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    'Allows Numeric values, one decimal point and BackSpace key
    Dim numbers As Windows.Forms.TextBox = sender
    If InStr("1234567890.", e.KeyChar) = 0 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Or (e.KeyChar = "." And InStr(numbers.Text, ".") > 0) Then
        e.KeyChar = Chr(0)
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_keyPress1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    'Allow Numeric values, BackSpace key. Disallows decimal point (i.e. dot) 
    Dim numbers As Windows.Forms.TextBox = sender
    If InStr("1234567890", e.KeyChar) = 0 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
        e.KeyChar = Chr(0)
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub TextBox_keyPress2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    'Allow selected values only
    If InStr("1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+=-", e.KeyChar) > 0 Then
        e.KeyChar = Chr(0)
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_keyPress3(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    'Martch function, Needs to add "Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions" at the top of Class
    'Allows Email values
    Dim Email As Windows.Forms.TextBox = sender
    If Email.Text <> "" Then
        Dim rex As Match = Regex.Match(Trim(Email.Text), "^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        If rex.Success = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a valid Email Address", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Email.BackColor = Color.Red
            Email.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Email.BackColor = Color.White
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Its almost the same as the most votes answer, but I edited `KeypressEvent` codes to make it simple and you can use this even you have to enter decimal numbers. Enjoy. :)

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing

    If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 2 Then

        AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_keyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)

     If (Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) _
                AndAlso (Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) _
                AndAlso (e.KeyChar <> Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(46)))) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub DGV_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DGV_TimeSheetMain.EditingControlShowing
    '       '*************Allow only Numbers in DataGridView*************
    Dim txtEdit As TextBox = e.Control
    'remove any existing handler
    RemoveHandler txtEdit.KeyPress, AddressOf TextEdit_Keypress
    AddHandler txtEdit.KeyPress, AddressOf TextEdit_Keypress
End Sub

Private Sub TextEdit_Keypress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    'Test for numeric value or backspace in first column
    If DGV.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
        If IsNumeric(e.KeyChar.ToString()) Or e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Back) Then
            e.Handled = False 'if numeric display
        Else
            e.Handled = True  'if non numeric don't display
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: THIS CODE ALLOWS BACKSPACE ALSO & WORKS PRETTY!

Answer (score 0):

Try This with lambda

```
Private Sub dgv_pararelhp_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgv_pararelhp.EditingControlShowing
    If dgv_pararelhp.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then'// change this optional your index column.
         AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, Sub(s_, e_)
                                                            If Char.IsDigit(CChar(CStr(e_.KeyChar))) = False Then e_.Handled = True
                                                         End Sub
       End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried Sathish answer but i can't  use the backspace so i tried this instead for the keypress event

```
Private Sub TextBox_keyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)

    If (Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) _
   AndAlso (Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) _
   AndAlso (e.KeyChar <> Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(46)))) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As         System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        AddHandler CType(e.Control, TextBox).KeyPress, AddressOf TextBox_keyPress
 End Sub
 Private Sub TextBox_keyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs)
        If Char.IsDigit(CChar(CStr(e.KeyChar))) = False Then e.Handled = True
        If Not (Char.IsDigit(CChar(CStr(e.KeyChar))) Or e.KeyChar = ".") Then e.Handled = True
        If e.KeyChar = " "c Then e.Handled = False
  End Sub
```

Comment: Please also provide some explanation and dont just paste a chunk of code.