# RadGrid Column Accept Only Decimals?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgrid

I have `RadGrid` and need to set column only accept `Decimals` (money format) and disable other characters. How do I set a column to accept only `Decimals` format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a specific column only accept numeric value in datagridview in Keypress event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645458/make-a-specific-column-only-accept-numeric-value-in-datagridview-in-keypress-eve)

Comment: other Links Not for Telerik WinForms

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [GridNumericColumn](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-column-types.html#numeric):

```
<telerik:GridNumericColumn DataField="MoneyAmount" DataType="System.Decimal" NumericType="Currency" HeaderText="Money Amount" SortExpression="MoneyAmount" UniqueName="MoneyAmount" DataFormatString="{0:C}"> 
</telerik:GridNumericColumn>
```

**EDIT**

If you are indeed asking about winforms, then the equivalent for the above is [GridViewDecimalColumn](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-columns-gridviewdecimalcolumn.html):

```
GridViewDecimalColumn currencyColumn = new GridViewDecimalColumn("Currency");
currencyColumn.FormatString = "{0:c}";
myGrid.Columns.Add(currencyColumn);
```

**EDIT2**

Try:

```
GridViewDecimalColumn unitPriceColumn = this.radGridView1.Columns["UnitPrice"] as GridViewDecimalColumn;
unitPriceColumn.FormatString = "Price: {0:C}";
unitPriceColumn.FormatInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
unitPriceColumn.NullValue = 0;
```

Check more on: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-columns-data-formatting.html

Comment: He has a "winforms" tag in the question. I guess you are talking about ASP.NET. But I also guess that there is winforms equivalent for this.

Comment: Good :) But your code example is VB.NET. He is asking about C# :)

Comment: @DianaNassar I have Column Already Added i don't wanna to add it again it has many other functions to add new one i wanna set it only accept Decimal

Comment: Thanks AGaian But Not working My column still Accept Characters