# testbox Validation in specific row in the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, textbox

I have a grid view with template columns and in the ItemTemplate i have textbox bounded with sqldatasource, I want make this text box in Row 3 only to type only number and on the other Rows to type normaly any thing ?

Comment: Try doing this in code behind using the function `RowDataBound` and applying validation rules if the row index is 3.

Answer (score 0):

- In EditingControlShowing, check that if the current cell lies in the desired column.
- Register a new event of KeyPress in EditingControlShowing(if above condition is true).
- Remove any KeyPress event added previously in EditingControlShowing.
- In KeyPress event, check that if key is not digit then cancel the input.

  ```
   private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,     DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
  {
  e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
  if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) //Desired Column
  {
  TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
  if (tb != null)
  {
      tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
  }
  }
  }

  private void Column1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
  {
  if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
  {
  e.Handled = true;
  }
  }
  ```

**Code Coutesy**-[Make a specific column only accept numeric value in datagridview in Keypress event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645458/make-a-specific-column-only-accept-numeric-value-in-datagridview-in-keypress-eve)

Comment: Thank you , but that make all the column, but i want to make one test box on that column on the 3rd row ?

Comment: Did you changed ColumnIndex == **[Desired column No]** and then you can writeanother IFLoop to find textbox of your choice . OR  as second option you can use RowDataBound event of gridview.