# Cell only can enter decimal character in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, cell, keycode

I have 6 columns in my datagridview. i want if i press enter, cell 5 will active and only can enter number. and this my code :

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
            DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5];
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell;
            dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);               
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

help me please..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645458/make-a-specific-column-only-accept-numeric-value-in-datagridview-in-keypress-eve

Comment: @MethodMan i already read that, but his use keychar method, how about use keycode?