# How to detect character in gridview cell at vb.net 2003

Tags: vb.net, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

I would like to allow number only in gridview cell value when user typing that field.My framework is dotnet 1.1 and Miscosoft visual studio .net 2003.Although I try to call gridview keypress event and key down event ,it does not fire.

Comment: have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12646259/2882256) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14639293/2882256) answer? It´s C# but you can pretty easy translate it to VB.

Comment: @Alex B ,Thank for your answer , but I doesn't found that event as ,EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e) event and CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

AddHandler yourGrid.EditingControlShowing, AddressOf yourGrid_EditingControlShowing

then cast the gridview textbox to TextBox