# how to check if datagridview cell content value is typed manually/modified

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, datagridview

In datagridview when i edit the content of cell and make some changes, i want to validate each character i type.
Iam confused, which event will be suitable for this. I tried cellvaluechanged event. But it is happening only for the
first time when you click the cell. But i want to validate each and everytime i type inside the cell. Please tell
me which event will be suitable for this.

What i tried:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, 
DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
if(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Reference")
{
//My code goes here
 }
}
```

Comment: Put a break point within your `_CellValueChanged` event handler, change some value and see whether it hits the break point or not, In my opinion it will definitely hit the breakpoint everytime you change the value and then redefine/refine your condition.

Comment: Is it possible to be more specific as to what kind of validation you want to do? There are built in features to accomplish cell validation or formatting the user input as they type. It is unclear exactly what you are trying to validate.

Comment: Example, one possible way to allow only numeric characters in a cell, then you can wire up the `EditingControlShowing` event to capture when a cell is being edited. From there you could check to see if the cell being edited is in the column that you only want to allow numeric input (example column 1), then inside the `EditingControlShowing` wire up another event method like “Column1_KeyPress”. From there you can handle the characters the user types and in this example… ignore any characters that are not numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I do find events in a DGV difficult to debug because they don't always fire when you expect them to. Sometimes they fire before or after a value is entered into a cell and in your example only occurs once.

The way I've got around this is to manipulating the event _CurrentCellDirtyState() below:

```
Private Sub datagridview1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles datagridview1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    if datagridview1.IsCurrentCellDirty
        datagridview1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub
```

This commits a dirtied cell (on keypress). You can now capture changes in the event _CellValueChanged() on each input. The below example enables a save button on a changed cell value.

```
Private Sub datagridview1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles datagridview1.CellValueChanged
    btnSave.Enabled = true
End Sub
```

However if you want to perform validation I suggest you follow the example in the following link.

[Make a specific column only accept numeric value in datagridview in Keypress event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645458/make-a-specific-column-only-accept-numeric-value-in-datagridview-in-keypress-eve#14639293)

You can build your own validation into the _KeyPress() event. I've used both of these methods together for most of my datagridviews.